# Why does the Codeanywhere container not open and keep saying "Restore in Progress"?

Tags: php, codeanywhere

I recently created a PHP container at codeanywhere.com. Today I was coding and went away for half an hour without closing the project, but when I came back the container just kept loading. Then I closed the browser, signed in and tried again, but the container kept loading. Then I clicked "restart", and now no files are accessible but the container keeps saying "Restore in progress". See the screenshot to see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem, the solution is:
1. Rename your container
2. Restart

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! FYI, was able to rename back to original name and restart again immediately after.